# How to replace character a by character b, and character c by d, in a string with regex

Tags: regex, julia

Given the string "ABBA", how can I replace, for example, characters A -> K and B -> I giving "KIIK" as result using `regex`?

I am using `regex101`as a tester.

Comment: These would be two regex operations that can be done with the substitution function on regex101.com

Comment: You can't replace using regex, which language are you using?

Comment: Generally speaking, you would need two separate regex replacements to achieve what you want.  As you can see from Regex101, under the replacement tab, there is only an input for a single replacement.  You can _target_ both `A` and `B` for replacement, but the tool you are using only admits a single replacement.

Comment: I am using `Julia`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to be fast you can hardcode this e.g. like this:

```
function replacer(s)
    out = IOBuffer(sizehint=sizeof(s))
    foreach(c -> write(out, c == 'A' ? 'K' : c == 'B' ? 'I' : c), s)
    return String(take!(out))
end
```

And now you have (I am also showing other options how `replace` can be called):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> s = "ABBAX"^100;

julia> @btime replacer($s);
  3.663 μs (4 allocations: 736 bytes)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, r"A" => "K"), r"B" => "I");
  31.300 μs (8 allocations: 1.59 KiB)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, "A" => "K"), "B" => "I");
  16.400 μs (8 allocations: 1.59 KiB)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, 'A' => 'K'), 'B' => 'I');
  13.300 μs (8 allocations: 1.59 KiB)

julia> s = "ABBAX"^1000;

julia> @btime replacer($s);
  35.000 μs (4 allocations: 5.19 KiB)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, r"A" => "K"), r"B" => "I");
  316.100 μs (8 allocations: 12.25 KiB)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, "A" => "K"), "B" => "I");
  159.900 μs (8 allocations: 12.25 KiB)

julia> @btime replace(replace($s, 'A' => 'K'), 'B' => 'I');
  128.800 μs (8 allocations: 12.25 KiB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering the comments, you may be looking for something like this.

```
result = replace("ABBA", r"A" => "K")
result = replace(result, r"B" => "I")
println(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace just these 2 or if you want to do some mapping of characters that cannot be described mathematically you can do it like this:

```
subs = Dict("A" => "K", "B" => "I");
println(replace("ABBA", r"[AB]" => s -> subs[s]))
```

where `subs` is the `Dict` of your substitutions

If you want to move each character "by 10 "  `A` to `K`, `B` to `L`, `C` to `M` etc. until `Z` you can do it like this

```
println(replace("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 
        r"[A-Z]" => s -> string(only(s) + 10 - ((only(s) + 10 <= 'Z') ? 0 : 26))))
```

`- ((only(s) + 10 <= 'Z') ? 0 : 26)` is responsible for reverting back to `A` once you exceed `Z`.